# How to redirect https to http with iptables command

Tags: firewall, iptables, openwrt, captivenetwork, captiveportal

There is a captive portal, named nodogsplash, running on my OpenWrt router. When a preauthenticated user visit a http url, browser will popup a webpage lead user to authenticate. But when user visit a https url, nothing happend.

I want the browser always pop up the autheticate webpage both visiting http and https urls.

I tried the following command, but only worked on http requests. When I visit a https domain name, it won't redirect to 192.168.88.210.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.88.210:80
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -m multiport --dport 80,443 -j MASQUERADE
```

I read the [github discussion](https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash/issues/3), but still don't know how to resolve this. Anyone can help me with iptables?

Comment: @kixorz is right. Youn can't redirect trafic 443 to 80/8080 with iptables.

Comment: @acj Thansk for your reply. Is there any easy and simple solution to slove this problem?

Comment: [Read this post](http://www.maravento.com/2013/03/firewall.html) to know how to configure iptables in 80/8080/443 (translate it)

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve this problem with `iptables`. With your approach, the browser would use regular `http` to connect to `https` server expecting SSL client. This is not possible. You need to run a simple HTTP web server on port 80 `http` and perform `Location header` redirect to the `https` URL.

Comment: Thansk for you reply. Is there any simple solution to let captive portal jump to authentication page when I visit https pages? NodogSplash used libhttpd which don't support https.

Comment: @daniel Unfortunately that's not possible without browser certificate error.